# Plotting a function which depends of another function

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to do a simple task but for some reason, Mathematica doesn't show the graphs for yavg1 or yavg2.

```
    T = 8;
yt[k_] := 
  k*HeavisideTheta[k] - 2*(k - T/4)*HeavisideTheta[k - T/4] + 
   2*(k - T*3/4)*HeavisideTheta[k - T*3/4] - (k - T)*
    HeavisideTheta[k - T];
y[k_] := yt[Mod[k, T]];
yavg1[k_] := (y[k] + y[k - 1] + y[k - 2])/3;
yavg2[k_] := (y[k - 1] + y[k] + y[k + 1])/3;

Show[Plot[y[k], {k, 0, 20}], Plot[yavg1, {k, 0, 20}], 
 Plot[yavg2, {k, 0, 20}]]
```

The idea is to get something like this:
[image]

But I get this:

[image]

(The first graph of the second image should look like the first image).
In the first place, I tried just using "Set" instead of "SetDelayed" then I changed to SetDelayed just to see if that helps considering the recursive function.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to call `yavg1[k]` and `yavg2[k]` not `yavg1` and `yavg2`when using `SetDelay`.

```
Show[Plot[y[k], {k, 0, 20}], Plot[yavg1[k], {k, 0, 20}], Plot[yavg2[k], {k, 0, 20}]]
```

[image]